# Android tablet pc with a Nokia phone 3G data connection

Tags: 3g, tablet-pc

This is technical question to check the possibilities of the scenario. Is it possible to use Nokia phone's (Lumia, N9, symbain phone, S40) 3G data connection with a Android tablet pc?

Or any way to use phone's 3G data connection with tablet pc?

I have a unlimited data connection for my phone. But I don't use it that much. So I'm planning to use it with the tablet pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep its possible easily if :
1. your tab is rooted
2. your tab supports usb host mode or otg mode (you could either check it on net or download usb host diagnostics) (just click start diagnostic)

procedure 
Downoad ppp widget
configure your apn according to pc suite settings 
then plug in your  phone via usb on nokia pc suite mode
now wait 10s and click connect
you are now done

(pls switch your wifi off as ppp widget creates virual wifi for your tab)
any inquiries contsct rld0989@gmail.com (don't be rest less I only check my gmail once a day)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Never got such nice support. I was planning to buy tab if I have this kind of 3g connectivity for the tab. I will buy it asap. Then I will try to follow your steps. In case I'm unsuccessful, I will ask u then. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to use your phone as a modem, connected to the tablet via a USB cable, as long as you have
(1)  an APN from your network operator to make a data connection via their network,  and
(2) suitable device drivers for the phone.  On Windows, smartphones are plug and play, but I don't have any experience using them with Android.

On the tablet, you also need some software to control the modem - something like the Mobile Broadband Connect 3.0 application listed on [here](http://softwaretopic.informer.com/android-vodafone-mobile-broadband/)

You can write a simple connection app yourself using the [Android Telephony Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html).

Alternatively, you could connect manually, using AT commands with a suitable AT command program (in Windows, it would be Hyperterminal).  [This thread](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-applications/21625-hyperterminal-like-app.html) describes a possible equivalent for Android.
Standard AT commands to make a data connection are described in the [3gpp TS27.007 specification.](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm)
There are a lot of variations for different manufacturers, but making a simple connect should be possible using the standard commands.